# What is the expected valued of this problem ? And what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Imagine a game, where you have to pass n successive levels.

$\frac{1}{2}$ of the players get past the first level.

$\frac{1}{3}$ of the players get past the second level, given that they've passed the first level.

$\frac{1}{4}$ of the players get past the third level, given that they've passed the second level.

What is the expected value of level at which a random player stops?

What I thought was:
The Probability of passing the second level is $\frac{1}{3}$(probability of winning the second game) * $\frac{1}{2}$(probability of passing the first level) = $\frac{1}{6}$ .

The Probability of passing the third level is $\frac{1}{6}$* $\frac{1}{4}$= $\frac{1}{24}$.

So in general the probability of winning the n-th game is $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$.

Knowing that the expected value of a random Variable is given by:

$$ E[X] =\sum_{i = 0}^n {iP(X=i)}= \sum_{i = 0}^n {\frac{i}{(i+1)!}} = 1 $$

Which apparently is incorrect.

[Here's my professor answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCB4E.jpg)
(At the beginning of his supposition he says "Let X be the level")

Can someone explain how he arrives to the conclusion that the answer is indeed $e-1$, I mean why he doesn't use the normal Expected Value formula ?

Thanks to everyone who will take some of their time even to read this far.

Comment: $e=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{i!}$.  Your expression is missing the $i=0$ term.

Comment: @lulu I noticed that I made more than a mistake in writing thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the edits.  You have $E=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac i{(i+1)!}$ which is clearly not $1$.

Comment: In general, I can't follow what you wrote.  The probability that you stop on level $i$ is not $\frac 1{(i+1)!}$.  That isn't even true for $i=2$...the probability that you stop on level $2$ is $\frac 12\times \frac 23=\frac 13$.  Your professor is using the fact that $E[X]=\sum_iP(X>i)$ which definitely simplifies the calculation.

Comment: @lulu try putting on wolfram $\sum_{i=0} ^n \frac{i}{(i+1!)}$

Comment: It is $1$ if $n=\infty$ but not otherwise. I thought your edits were intended to add $n$ back to the picture.  But, the bigger problem with what you wrote is that $P(X=i)$ is not $\frac 1{(i+1)!}$.

Comment: @lulu why not  ?

Comment: Look at the example I gave you.  The probability that you stop on level $2$ is $\frac 12\times \frac 23=\frac 13$.  For level $3$ it is $\frac 12\times \frac 13\times \frac 34=\frac 18$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a rv defined on non-negative integers, the mean can be calculated also in the following way

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_x P[X>x]$$

$x=0,1,2,...$

thus the solution is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+i)!}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1^k}{(k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1^k}{(k)!}-1=e-1$$

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you explain me where this formula comes from ?

Comment: @JoseManuel : look here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820765/proof-expected-value-x-of-non-negative-integer

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm actually stuying engineering and this kind of things are not taught with this depth.

Comment: @JoseManuel : in the next answer I show you an alternative proof of the same property but extended in the continuous case

Answer (score 0):

alternative proof for Continuous rv's

Suppose you have a continuous non negative rv.

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty} x f(x)dx$$

Let's prove that

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F(x)]dx$$

that is the same as saying $\sum P[X>x]$ but in the continuous case

To prove it let's solve the integral by parts

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F(x)]dx=\underbrace{\Bigg[ x(1-F(x))\Bigg]_{0}^{\infty}}_{=0}+\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$$

(to prove that the first addend is zero you can easy solve the limit with de l'Hôpital)